# inplace quicksort with random pivot C implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I need to implement a quicksort algorithm that uses random pivot; I'm working with big matrices, so i can't afford the worst case.

Now, I've found this [implementation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/explain-the-quick-sort-technique-in-c-language) that works correctly, but it uses as pivot the first element.

I've modified it to fit my scenario (I'm working with Sparse Matrices, and I need to sort the elements by "row index, col index") and this is what I have:

```
void quicksortSparseMatrix(struct sparsematrix *matrix,int first,int last){
    
    int i, j, pivot, temp_I, temp_J;
    double temp_val;
    

    if(first<last){
        pivot=first;            //(rand() % (last - first + 1)) + first;
        
        i=first;
        j=last;     

        while(i<j){
            while(lessEqual(matrix,i, pivot)&&i<last)
                i++;
            while(greater(matrix,j, pivot))
                j--;
            if(i<j){   
                temp_I = matrix->I[i];
                temp_J = matrix->J[i]; 
                temp_val = matrix->val[i];
                matrix->I[i] = matrix->I[j];
                matrix->J[i] = matrix->J[j];
                matrix->val[i] = matrix->val[j];
                matrix->I[j]=temp_I;
                matrix->J[j]=temp_J;
                matrix->val[j]=temp_val;
            }
        
        }


    temp_I = matrix->I[pivot];
    temp_J = matrix->J[pivot]; 
    temp_val = matrix->val[pivot];
    matrix->I[pivot] = matrix->I[j];
    matrix->J[pivot] = matrix->J[j];
    matrix->val[pivot] = matrix->val[j];
    matrix->I[j]=temp_I;
    matrix->J[j]=temp_J;
    matrix->val[j]=temp_val;
    
    quicksortSparseMatrix(matrix,first,j-1);
    quicksortSparseMatrix(matrix,j+1,last);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that some of the matrices i'm working with are almost sorted and the algorithm runs extremely slow. I want to modify my algorithm to make it use random pivot, but if I apply the change you see commented in the code above `pivot=(rand() % (last - first + 1)) + first;`, the algorithm does not sort the data correctly.

Can anyone help me figure out how to change the algorithm to use a random pivot and sort the data correctly?

EDIT: this is the struct sparsematrix definition, I don't think you need it, but for completeness...

```
struct sparsematrix {
    int M, N, nz;   
    int *I, *J;
    double *val;
};
```

Comment: you want the `pivot` between `first` and `last`, so should it be : `first+ rand() % (last - first);` ?

Comment: yes, if put `first+ rand() % (last - first);` the pivot is between `first` and `last`, but the algorithm doesn't sort correctly

Comment: @fabianod - rand() could return 0. Try `pivot = matrix[ ... first+1+(rand() % (last - first));]`. pivot needs to be a value, not an index.

Comment: @rcgldr in my case i called pivot the index because i cannot use `<` for "less than" etc, but i need to call a function that compare row_index and col_index given 2 indices. Anyway, it doesn't works.

Comment: After you select the random pivot index, swap that element with the element at first. Then use the algorithm you have which assumes that the pivot is the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot should be a value, not an index. The first comparison should be lessthan (not lessthanorequal), which will also eliminate the need for checking for `i < last` . After swapping, there should be `i++` and `j--` . The last two lines should be `quicksortSparseMatrix(matrix,first,j);` and `quicksortSparseMatrix(matrix,i,last);` , for this variation of Hoare partition scheme. Example code for array:

```
void QuickSort(int *a, int lo, int hi)
{
int i, j;
int p, t;
    if(lo >= hi)
        return;
    p = a[lo + 1 + (rand() % (hi - lo))];
    i = lo;
    j = hi;
    while (i <= j){
        while (a[i] < p)i++;
        while (a[j] > p)j--;
            if (i > j)
                break;
            t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
            i++;
            j--;
    }
    QuickSort(a, lo, j);
    QuickSort(a, i, hi);
}
```

---

A merge sort on an array of indexes to rows of matrix may be faster: more moves of the indexes, but fewer compares of rows of matrix. A second temp array of indexes will be needed for merge sort.